# My custom jquery is not affecting woocommerce after load then in function.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am still developing the site http://verocoffee1.wpengine.com/shop/carimali-bubble/ and I did a few changes using jquery, they were all at the footer, I learned that is not the correct way to do. So I copied all to a file called veroscript.js and inserted it in the function.php

```
function sd_scripts_enqueue() {

    wp_register_script(
          'veroscript'
        , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/veroscript.js'
        , array(
            'jquery'
        )
        , '0'
        , true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script('veroscript');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sd_scripts_enqueue', 99999);
```

However after that all the code that should affects woocommerce is not working anymore.
Should I do something different for woocommerce?

Comment: Try changing the register handle from "veroscript" to "my-veroscript"

Comment: Chrome dev console shows `veroscript.js` has loaded on your website so there's nothing wrong with the above code but your `veroscript.js` file has an error: `Uncaught TypeError: e(...).tinyNav is not a function`. This error is stopping your page from executing the script.

Comment: Thank Input!!!! All sorted now :)